# Is there any way to move x86 machine code?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, exe, machine-code

Let's say I have a small block of machine code at address `X`, that's part of an EXE (PE). It contains all kind of instructions including those with relative addresses. How could I move this code to address `Y` without changing its behaviour? I don't want to write my own decompiler. Some existing library or a trick, maybe?

Comment: if it's relative addressed, then it shouldn't care WHERE it's running from. all the addresses are going to be relative to some base address. you'd need to figure out where that base address is stored, and update it with the new one, and everything else "just works" because they're doing "base address + x bytes"-type calculations.

Comment: Right, if they're all relative memory addresses, it should run anywhere you put it.  What is your use case?  Doesn't the EXE loader do this for you already?  Or are you trying to write yet another virus that I'm going to have to clean off my computer and send you a bill for the lost time?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I want to make hook in an exe. Place a jmp at address `X`, execute hook, and then execute original code taken from address `X`, but at address `Y`. It's a mod for a 15-year-old computer game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard thing to do in the 'old school' days is to leave your code at 'x', replace the first few bytes (say it was 3) with a jump to the new code. At the end of the new code you execute the code that you replaced at 'x', then jump back to 'x'+3

Comment: Yea but I can only replace code without relative addresses.

Comment: Based on your comments you do not need to move code, the solution @Marichyasana has provided does not move any code, it injects a detour in the existing code to a new piece of code and then reroutes back to the original once the detour is complete. Of course you do not need to reroute back to the original routine, but you need to ensure that you leave the stack and registers in the expected state for the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Generally impossible, but oblivious if the code is carefully written. See: [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).